# How do I write tablature on this site?

Tags: discussion, jtab

Just like the title says, will something like this work?

> G7 : 334353
>
> str3:  6~  7...  6... ....    (pinky) 
> G7  G7  G7 G7 G7

It looks dirty.

Comment: Well its not quite tabulature, but perhaps you'll be better off with MuML?

http://doc.rhavin.de/MuML/

Comment: Nope, I don't read sheet music and probably will not learn.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It needs to be in a code-block, so either start each line with 4 spaces, or click the `{}` button above the text-edit frame and type shift-enter for each new line (it automatically adds the 4 spaces). If you copy/paste into the edit box, you can highlight the section and click `{}` or hit ctrl-k to toggle the 4 space indent.

The actual syntax is specified by the [jTab library](http://jtab.tardate.com/). You should be able to use the previewer on that site to see what it will look like before you post (since tabs won't be rendered in post previews on the site).

Comment: Great tip about Shift-Enter to keep the indent!

Comment: Also, interesting about the edit limit. I didn't know anything about this. I'm always editing a lot; any idea what the limit is? (I could just check on MetaSE...)

Comment: Here's the main page about it: [What are Community Wiki posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/). So it looks like the limit is 10. But this number can be changed on a per-site basis, and has already been raised on some sites (like codegolf).

Comment: A note for posterity: [all forms of automatic conversion to community-wiki status were disabled in May 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/335251) (just a few months after this answer was posted), which means repeated edits don't result in auto-conversion to community wiki status. (You should still avoid constantly editing a post to make minor changes, though; doing so repeatedly bumps the post and clutters the revision history.)

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks, Much better.